# Howto expand 2D NumPy array by copy bottom row and right column?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a `2D` `NumPy` array and I hope to expand its size on both dimensions by copying the bottom row and right column.

For example, from `2x2`:

```
[[0,1],
 [2,3]]
```

to `4x4`:

```
[[0,1,1,1],
 [2,3,3,3],
 [2,3,3,3],
 [2,3,3,3]]
```

What's the best way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here, the hstack and vstack functions can come in handy. For example,

```
In [16]: p = array(([0,1], [2,3]))
In [20]: vstack((p, p[-1], p[-1]))
Out[20]:
    array([[0, 1],
           [2, 3],
           [2, 3],
           [2, 3]])
```

And remembering that p.T is the transpose:

So now you can do something like the following:

```
In [16]: p = array(([0,1], [2,3]))
In [22]: p = vstack((p, p[-1], p[-1]))
In [25]: p = vstack((p.T, p.T[-1], p.T[-1])).T
In [26]: p
Out[26]:
array([[0, 1, 1, 1],
       [2, 3, 3, 3],
       [2, 3, 3, 3],
       [2, 3, 3, 3]])
```

So the 2 lines of code should do it...

Comment: I have tried it. it works much better than my naive for loop copy for each column/row. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make an empty array and copy whatever rows, columns you want into it.

```
def expand(a, new_shape):
    x, y = a.shape
    r = np.empty(new_shape, a.dtype)
    r[:x, :y] = a
    r[x:, :y] = a[-1:, :]
    r[:x, y:] = a[:, -1:]
    r[x:, y:] = a[-1, -1]
    return r
```

Comment: Cool. I like this function. it works for generic 2-D array size.